# How to import specific nodes from xml into treeview c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, treeview

I'm currently making a tool that have an xml file as input and want to display the data inside the xml in a treeview.The problem is I don't need to import all the data, just some specific ones.

I.E: i have this part of the xml file:

```
<grADI:ObjectTree>
    <grADI:Display>
      <grADI:StaticDisplayAttributes>
        <grADI:ModelIntErrPageId Value="OS_PAG65"/>          
        <grADI:SwapAxes Value="false"/>
      </grADI:StaticDisplayAttributes>
      <grADI:Layer>
        <grADI:StaticLayerAttributes>
          <grADI:ApplicationColorPalette Value="DRWSPC2"/>
          <grADI:ColorPaletteColorSpace Value="COLSPC2"/>   
        </grADI:StaticLayerAttributes>
        <grADI:ChangeableAttribute Mode="Fix" Type="AlphaVal" Value="100"/>
        <grADI:SignalSet>
          <grADI:Signal DataType="BOOL" Max="1" Min="0" Name="VolvoASample.ly_boBackground_act" SignalID="2" Type="Activate"/>
        </grADI:SignalSet>
   </grADI:Layer>
   <grADI:Layer>
        <grADI:StaticLayerAttributes>
          <grADI:ApplicationColorPalette Value="DRWSPC2"/>
          <grADI:ColorPaletteColorSpace Value="COLSPC2"/>   
        </grADI:StaticLayerAttributes>
        <grADI:ChangeableAttribute Mode="Fix" Type="AlphaVal" Value="100"/>
        <grADI:SignalSet>
          <grADI:Signal DataType="BOOL" Max="1" Min="0" Name="VolvoASample.ly_boBackground_act" SignalID="2" Type="Activate"/>
        </grADI:SignalSet>
   </grADI:Layer>
```

The output that i need in the treeview is :

```
     grADI:Display
         grADI:Layer
         grADI:Layer
```

I found a way to print all the nodes, but when I added the if statement to restrict just the nodes I need, I get an "Argument Out of Range Exception" error on this line " new_tree_node = tree_node.Nodes[i];"

```
         private void BindTreeViewText()
        {
            try
            {
                XmlDocument xml_doc = new XmlDocument();
                xml_doc.Load("grADIExportData.xml");
                treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xml_doc.Name));
                TreeNode rnode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
                AddText(xml_doc.DocumentElement, rnode);
                treeView1.ExpandAll();
            }
            catch(XmlException xe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(xe.Message);
            }
        }

          private void AddText(XmlNode xml_node, TreeNode tree_node)
                   {
                       XmlNode new_xml_node;
                       TreeNode new_tree_node;
                       XmlNodeList xml_list;
                       int i;
                       if(xml_node.HasChildNodes)
                       {
                           xml_list = xml_node.ChildNodes;
                           for(i=0;i<=xml_list.Count-1;i++)
                           {
                               new_xml_node = xml_node.ChildNodes[i];
                               if (new_xml_node.Name== "grADI:Display" || new_xml_node.Name == "grADI:Layer" )
                               {
                                   tree_node.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(new_xml_node.Attributes["Name"].Value));
                               }                            
                               new_tree_node = tree_node.Nodes[i];
                               AddText(new_xml_node, new_tree_node);

                           }
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           tree_node.Text = (xml_node.OuterXml).Trim();
                       }
                   }
```

Any ideas how I can change the code so it would only print the nodes that I want in the treeview?

Comment: It should be : new_tree_node = xml_list[i];

Comment: new_tree_node is TreeNode type, and xml_list[i] is XmlNode type.

Comment: The variable i is the number of items in xml_List, not tree_node.

Comment: if i use new_tree_node = xml_list[i], it will pop an convert error( can't convert from treenode to xmlnode)

Comment: You really want to set it to : new TreeNode(new_xml_node.Attributes["Name"].Value)  but this object has no name.  So make the Add two statement and give the object a variable name.

Comment: even if i give them names, i still get the error at line new_tree_node = xml_list[i]

Comment: Use the variable name instead of xml_list[i].